# Setting up a container to be of an exact width with twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a header image for a layout that I'm working on that is 1200px wide. The layout is fixed.

I'd like the container that wraps this image (and any container that wraps it up in the DOM hierarchy) to adapt to the 1200px. First thing I thought on doing was to just:

```
.container {
    width:1200px;
}
```

It works, but then what's the point of using bootstrap? And also, I'd probably be messing with the grid by forcing a width this way, right?

So, I tried to setup the grid to add up to 1200px, but still keep 12 columns, like this (I'm using sass):

```
$grid-column-width:         70px;
$grid-gutter-width:         32px;
```

However, I could only approximate (or go way above) 1200px, while keeping 12 columns. In this case, I got 1192px, which works, but is not optimal.

Here's the markup I'm using:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row-fluid">
       <div class="header-photo text-center span12"></div>
       <div class="row-fluid">
         ...
       </div>
         ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the SCSS that setups the header div:

```
div.header-photo {
  background-image: url(/images/header-photo.png);
  width: 1200px;
  height: 368px;
  h2,h3 {
    text-indent: -99999px;
  }
}
```

So, if I use span12, the other divs adapt to the size of the header-photo div, but only up to 1192px.

What would be the best approach to get the container to be of exactly 1200px?

1. force it with a CSS rule (like I tried doing) ?
2. A combo of the grid conf that I'm clueless about?
3. Tell the designer to make the header photo smaller/bigger so it adapts to another value?
4. ... ?

Any hints highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. But if I remember right. Doesn't bootstrap add some values for margin on the columns. I am assuming you aren't compensating for that which is probably why you are coming up short.

Comment: Hi Kris. Is that the gutter width? Also, when you say "compensating for that" you mean in the grid conf vars values? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should fix the container value by opening the bootsrap gem

Comment: I haven't a clue what you're referring to??